# Entity Framework Core not recognizing commands

Tags: entity-framework-core

I'm trying to build a Windows Forms application in Visual Studio 2022 using Entity Framework Core. I have the following packages installed in my project:

- Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore - v8.0.0
- Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design - v8.0.0
- Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer - v8.0.0
- Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools - v8.0.0

I tried to issue the following command in the Package Manager Console:

```
Scaffold-DbContext "Server=*****;Database=*****;Trusted_Connection=True;" 
     Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer 
     -OutputDir Model
```

But I get the following response:

> The term 'C:\Users<userid>.nuget\packages\microsoft.entityframeworkcore.tools\8.0.0\tools\init.ps1' is
> not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of
> the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
>
> At line:1 char:45 + ... rgs+=$_}; & 'C:\Users<userid>.nuget\packages\microsoft.entityframew ...
>
> - 
>
> ```
> + CategoryInfo       : ObjectNotFound: (C:\Users\<userid>...\tools\init.ps1:String) [], CommandNotFound   
> Exception  
> + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException  
>
> Scaffold-DbContext : The term 'Scaffold-DbContext' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
>
> At line:1 char:1  
> + Scaffold-DbContext "Server=*****;Database=*****;Trusted_Connection=Tr ...  
> + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~  
> + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Scaffold-DbContext:String) [], CommandNotFoundException  
> + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
> ```

Can someone tell me why it's complaining about the `init.ps1` file or why the `Scaffold-DbContext` command isn't being found? I've tried removing and re-adding the 4 packages I listed and restarting Visual Studio but the problem still exists.

Comment: can you `cd` to that .ps1 file? are you running VS as admin? sometimes it can be something like the setup is happening on one user, but then it looks for the file on your admin user and it doesn't exist on that profile. (if it's saying that `Scaffold-DbContext` is not found then you may not have something installed that you need installed.)

Comment: I can "cd" to that .ps1 file.  When I try opening the project in VS as admin, the Package Manager Console immediately shows the first error (the init.ps1 error) when VS opens.  I'm working on a locked-down system.  Could that be causing the error?  If so, any workaround?

Comment: you would need to install "something" (not 100% sure what) into the admin user profile. or maybe better is to not run VS as admin if possible.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix my problem by changing the command I was using to:

```
dotnet ef dbcontext scaffold "Server=*****;Database=*****;Trusted_Connection=True;TrustServerCertificate=True;" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -o Model
```